# Css3 Media Queries only work inside <head> tag

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been googling for two days now but cannot find an answer.... The problem is only in IE8 all other browser are doing fine...... I am using the following Js files to support Media Queries in IE8:

```
css3-mediaqueries.js
html5.js
```

The problem is that the media queries do not work when in an external stylesheet but when I put them inside the head section of the html file they start to work alright. The site is Wordpress. Any help would be great.

My Media Query code is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width:1075px) {
    #wrap {
        width:100%;
        max-width:98%;
    }
}
@media \0screen {
    img { 
        width: auto; /* for ie 8 */
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width:768px) {
    #wrap {width: 100%;}
    .grid {padding: 0;}
    #contentleft {width: 100%;}
    .grid > aside {float: none; margin: 0; width: auto; }
    #contentright {float: none;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set an empty style tag in your head tag.

```
 <style></style>
```

I had problems with media-queries declared in a link rel stylesheet and this resolved it for me.

Comment: Also had a similar problem, with `<link rel="stylesheet"...` - ended up just using `<style>@import(...)</style>` and it worked, though I'm not familiar with those specific js libraries.

Comment: Adding an empty style tag in my head tag do not slove the problem. I am unable to understand that if I put mediaqueries inside head tag they work fine and the same mediaqueries are in style.css they do not work, even a seperate stylesheet only for mediaqueries does not work.